# Closing generated jframe from swing after swingworker has finished

Tags: java

I have some work to be done in background where I do display a JFrame with progress bar in it, i need to dispose the JFrame when the swingworker has finished, dont know where to dispose it

```
 private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
   ProgressBarFRM.setIndeterminate(true);
   Start();

}                                 


public void Start(){
    SwingWorker<Boolean , Integer> worker = new SwingWorker<Boolean , Integer>(){
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
          // work .....
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {

        }

    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i couldn't find an answer to my question, I have changed the logic of my class by avoiding the SwingWorker and using a manually create JFrame in a class where it did what I want.